# Recommendations for VPN client software for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, vpn

In my scenario the built-in Windows 7 VPN system isn't able to connect using [L2TP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_2_Tunneling_Protocol).

So I would like to find out what people's recommendations are for third-party VPN client software that in particular works on Windows 7 and works well.

**Update:**

It's a VPN system built into a [Check Point](http://www.checkpoint.com) firewall.

Comment: What's on the other end? (what sort of VPN appliance or app are you connecting with)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Success!**

As of March 2010, [Check Point](http://checkpoint.com) have a Windows 7 64-bit compatible client side VPN application.

Version seems to be R73 with filename:

> 'Check_Point_Endpoint_Connect_R73_For_Windows_835000022.exe'

available for download [here](https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal/user/anon/page/default.psml/media-type/html?action=portlets.DCFileAction&eventSubmit_doGetdcdetails=&fileid=10653).

It was quite simple to setup too simple username/password authentication.

[image: Main Options]

[image: Sub Properties]

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on the type of VPN you're trying to connect to. I have had great success with Aventail's SonicWall SSL client (provided by Aventail) and others have reported success with CheckPoint's client in Windows 7.

Check with the VPN manufacturer and see if they offer a client of their own. Many firewalls/VPN's will have proprietary clients that can be configured with a "catch-all" client, but there's usually a manufacturer provided one.  Most companies have been quick to update their software for Windows 7, as well.

64-bit ready clients might be a little slower, but again - most are coming around.

Comment: Ditto that it depends what you're connecting to. Often times VPNs will be set up so that you must use the VPN client from the manufacturer. For example, many Cisco VPNs are set up so that you must use the Cisco client. Kinda sucks... but, so it goes.

Comment: Seems to be the case there isn't any 64-bit Windows 7 capable software from CheckPoint yet.

Comment: My Checkpoint info was completely anecdotal - http://twitter.com/drub0y/status/5202156619

Answer (score 1):

Shrew Soft  VPN Client.  I am using it on my laptop with Windows 7 64 bit ultimate with no problems.

Comment: I actually had a bit of trouble with this application, conflicting with my network cards, my solution was to do a system restore to back out what ever went wrong.

Comment: Shrew Soft is terrible, especially when used with the most recent update to Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Greenbow](http://www.thegreenbow.com/vpn.html). It supports Windows 7 and has a heap of features.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried VPN Client software from [NCP Secure Communications](http://www.ncp-e.com/)

The download page for their software is [here](http://www.ncp-e.com/en/downloads/software.html).

But sadly it also didn't work with the [Check Point](http://www.checkpoint.com/) VPN system, even after a lengthy tweaking of all the configuration settings.